# How to combine SoundEffectInstances into a new Sound File /mp3 or wav

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm working on the new WindowsPhone platform.  I have a few intances of a SoundEffectInstance that I would like to combine into a new single Sound file (either SoundEffectInstance, SoundEffect or MediaElement, it does not matter.)  I then want to save that file as an mp3 to the phone.

How do I do that?  Normally, I would try to send all the files to a bytearray but I'm not sure if that is the correct method here, or how to convert the bytearray into an MP3 format sound.

So for example  I have SoundEffectInstance soudBackground, playing from 0 - 5 seconds.  I then have SoundEffectInstance chime playing from 3 - 4 seconds, and SoundEffectInstance foreground playing from  3.5 to 7 seconds.   I want to combine all these into a single mp3 file that lasts 7 seconds long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two task that you are trying to accomplish here:

- Combine several sound files into a single sound file
- Save the resulting file as an MP3.

As far as I have found thus far you will have a good bit of challenges with item 2. To date I have not found a pure .Net MP3 encoder. All the ones I find rely on P/Invokes to native code (Which of course won't work on the phone).

As for combining the files, you don't want to treat them as a SoundEffectInstance. That class is only meant for playing and it abstracts most of the details of the sound file away. Instead you will need to treat the sound files as arrays of ints. I'm going to assume that the sample rate on all three sound files is the exact same and that these are 16-bit recordings. I am also going to assume that these wave files are recorded in mono. I'm keeping the scenario simple for now. You can extend upon it with stereo and various sample rates after you've mastered this simpler scenario.

The first 48 bytes of the wave files is nothing but header. Skip past that (for now) and read the contents of the wave files into their own arrays.  Once they are all read we can start mixing them together. Ignoring the time differences in which you want to start playing these sounds if we wanted to start producing a sample that is the combined result of all three we could do it by adding the values in the sound file array together and writing that out to an array to hold our result. But there's a problem. 16-bit numbers can only go up to 32,767 (and down to -32,768). If the combined value of all three sounds were to go beyond these limits you'll get really bad distortion. The easiest (though not necessarily the best) way to handle this is to consider the maximum number of simultaneous sounds that will play and scale the values down accordingly. From the 3.5 second to 4 second mark you will have all three sounds playing. So we will scale by dividing by three.  Another way is to sum up the sound samples using a data type that can go beyond this range and then normalizing the values back to this range when you are done mixing them together.

Let's define some parameters.

```
int SamplesPerSecond = 22000;
int ResultRecordingLength = 7;
short[] Sound01;
short[] Sound02;
short[] Sound03;
int[] ResultantSoundBuffer;
short[] ProcessedResultSoundBuffer;

//Insert code to populate sound array's here. 
// Sound01.Length will equal 5.0*SamplesPerSecond
// Sound02.Length will equal 1.0*SamplesPerSecond
// Sound03.Length will equal 3.5*SamplesPerSecond

ResultantSound = new int[ResultRecordingLength*SamplesPerSecond];
```

Once you've got your sound files read and the array prepared for receiving the resulting file you can start rendering. There's several ways we could go about this. Here is one:

```
void InitResultArray(int[] resultArray)
{
   for(int i=0;i<resultArray.Length;++i)
   {
      resultArray[i]=0;
   }
}

void RenderSound(short[] sourceSound, int[] resultArray, double timeOffset)
{
   int startIndex = (int)(timeOffset*SamplesPerSecond);
   int readIndex = 0;
   for(int readIndex=0;((readIndex<sourceSound.Length)&&(readIndex+sourceSound<resultArray.Length;++readIndex)
   {
      resultArray[readIndex+startIndex] += (int)sourceSound[readIndex];
   }
}

 RangeAdjust(int[] resultArray)
{
   int max = int.MinimumValue;
   int min = int.MaximumValue;
   for(int i=0;i<resultArray;++i)
   {
     max = Math.Max(max, resultArray[i]);
     min = Math.Min(min, resultArray[i]);
   }
   //I want the range normalized to [-32,768..32,768]
   //you may want to normalize differently.
   double scale = 65536d/(double)(max-min);
   double offset = 32767-(max*scale);
   for(int i=0;i<resultArray.Length;++i)
   {
      resultArray[i]= (scale*resultArray[i])+offset;
   }
}
```

You would call InitResultAttay to ensure the result array is filled with zeros (I believe it is by default, but I still prefer to explicitly set it to zero) and then call RenderSound() for each sound that you want in your result. After you've rendered your sounds call RangeAdjust to normalize the sound.  All that's left is to write it to a file. You'll need to convert from ints back to shorts.

```
short[] writeBuffer = new short[ResultantSound.Length];
for(int i=0;i<writeBuffer.Length;++i)
   writeBuffer[i]=(short)ResultantSound[i];
```

Now the mixed sound is all ready to write to the file. There is just one thing missing, you need to write the 48 byte wave header before writing the file. I've written code on how to do that here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/WpVoiceMemo.aspx

Comment: Thanks Joel... This can all be done on the phone? I was starting to believe it wasn't possible.  How do I get the bit array from the sound file? Or does it have to be downloaded from the net to do that?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the Wave files are coming from. It can be from the net, deployed with your project, or where ever as long your code has access to them. Yes, this is all possible on the phone. But the day is late and I must hop in my car to engage in battle with the local traffic. Will try to do a write with more details this week.

Comment: How do I get the bit array from the sound file? Waiting for more details! please

Comment: @arsenium - in general you would first read the first 48 bytes of the file. The information it contains includes the length of the file, whether the samples are 8 bit or 16 bit, and the number of channels the sound has (generally 1 or 2, but it can be more for surround sound). Immediately following these 48 bytes are the sample data.

Comment: @Shafiq Abbas - I think you would need to share more details to invoke a remedy. If you have a solution it would be helpful to the community if you also shared it.

Comment: @Joel  Could you add an example?